# About SharePoint 2010 "select" column

Tags: jquery

I have a question related to "select" column. The "select" column little arrow to select an item, I wanna set the color to blue or any other color, when user select the arrow.

Any ideas.,really appreciatable.

Thanks 
Ven

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need should be explained here:

http://code.google.com/p/select-box/

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: Did it help u ? Plz mark as answer if it did

Answer (score 0):

Use below css.

```
img[src*='rbsel.gif'] 
{
BACKGROUND:Blue;
WIDTH: 20px; /*this must equal the width of your new image*/
HEIGHT: 0px; 
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; 
PADDING-LEFT: 0px; 
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; 
PADDING-TOP: 20px /*This must equal the height of your new image it will pad the double arrow out of view*/
}

img[src*='rbunsel.gif'] {

BACKGROUND:Green;
WIDTH: 20px; /*this must equal the width of your new image*/
HEIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; 
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;  
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;  
PADDING-TOP: 20px /*This must equal the height of your new image it will pad the double arrow out of view*/

}
```